# How to share logic among functions?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, coding-style

I came across with an issue when developing a code with some similar blocks inside my code. My question is: **What is the best approach to share logic among functions?**

Example:

The functions below contains the same if/else logic. How can we refactor this code in order to have a more concise and maintainable code?

```
// pseudo code...

const hirer = 'woman';

const getPositions = () => {
 if (hirer === 'woman') {
   getPositionsFromWomen();
   // do other stufs here...
 } else if (hirer === 'man') {
   getPositionFromMen();
   // do other stufs here...
 }
 // maybe other stufs here...
}


const hire = (hirer) => {
  if (hirer === 'woman') {
    increaseWomenHiringRate(hirer);
    // do other stufs here...
  } else if (hirer === 'man') {
    increaseMenHiringRate(hirer);
    // do other stufs here...
  }
 setPositionClosed();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fairly standard way is to *parameterize* the logic. In this case, perhaps by putting the logic in a function that accepts functions it will call for each logical branch:

```
const hirer = 'woman';

const hirerDispatch = (hirer, ifWoman, ifMan) => hirer === 'woman' ? ifWoman() : ifMan();

const getPositions = () => {
  hirerDispatch(hirer, getPositionsFromWomen, getPositionFromMen);
  // maybe other stuff here...
};

const hire = (hirer) => {
  hirerDispatch(hirer, () => increaseWomenHiringRate(hirer), () => increaseMenHiringRate(hirer));
  setPositionClosed();
};
```

More complex parameterization might involve passing in an object with function properties for the branches, including arguments to pass along (so we don't need wrappers like we do in `hire`), etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to pass actions as Javascript object as parameter to your logic containing methods. This is how your code would look like :

```
const hirer = 'woman';

var positionHire = {
    women: getPositionsFromWomen,
    men: getPositionsFromMen
}
const getPositions = (hirer, positionHire) => {
 if (hirer === 'woman') {
   getPositionsFromWomen();
   // do other stufs here...
 } else if (hirer === 'man') {
   getPositionFromMen();
   // do other stufs here...
 }
 // maybe other stufs here...
}

var hireRate = {
    women: increaseWomenHiringRate,
    men: increaseMenHiringRate
}

const hire = (hirer, hireRate) => {
  if (hirer === 'woman') {
    increaseWomenHiringRate(hirer);
    // do other stufs here...
  } else if (hirer === 'man') {
    increaseMenHiringRate(hirer);
    // do other stufs here...
  }
 setPositionClosed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if/else are switches on a type (`hirer`). Therefore, you could [Replace conditional with polymorphism](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html). You'd need a name for the second function, which I'd guess at `determineHiringRate()` (although I'm not sure that's the right name).

Here's a class diagram of the solution:

[image]